# Why is this stored procedure returning the incorrect results for the second select?

Tags: mysql

When I execute the MySql stored procedure below, the number of results for the 1st select are correct, but it seems to be ignoring the parameter for the second select, because it is returning all records.  For the first select, it returns 1 contact, but for the second select, it is returning all addresses for all contacts.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'dbadmin'@'%'
PROCEDURE ContactsDB.GetContact(IN contactId INT)
BEGIN
SELECT Id,
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       Company,
       Title,
       Email
FROM Contacts
WHERE Id = contactId;

SELECT Id,
       ContactId,
       AddressType,
       StreetAddress,
       City,
       StateId,
       PostalCode
FROM Addresses
WHERE ContactId = contactId;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of MySQL you're using, but if it's 5 or greater it could be a case sensitivity thing. Your parameter name matches the column name, the second query might just be comparing the column to itself and returning all rows.

Comment: Don't you think this should be a comment, rather than an answer?

Comment: Which is why experienced sql developers adopt naming conventions like input params are preceded with an underscore: eg _contact_id not contactId and database object names are always lower case with underscores to seperate words and make it all legible: eg contact_id not ContactId

Comment: This was the problem.  I changed the parameter name and it brought back the correct data. Thanks.